# How to account for still-missing {{data}}?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I need to display information in a component via

```
<div>{{information.name}}</div>
```

`information` is declared in `data()`:

```
data() {
  return {
    information: {}
  }
}
```

The actual content of `information` is queried at `mount()` time via a `fetch()` call, and therefore I get an initial error because `information.name` is not known yet.

**What is the correct way to account for that situation?**

What I do today is to bootstrap the object information with some fake data, but it becomes cumbersome as the size growths:

```
data() {
  return {
    information: {name: ''}
  }
}
```

Comment: If you dont need access to DOM during fetch, you should use created instead of mounted. If you dont need these properties to be reactive(information property values doesnt change after fetch), you can force rerender after fetch. Otherwise, you have to boostrap properties(becomes reactive) or to watch property information=>rerender.

Comment: @bigless: thanks for the information. How `created()` is useful here - since `fetch` is asynchronous, it may not have the results when Vue moves to the mount phase (this is what I actually see - an error in the mount stage despite having the fetch in created)

Comment: Im not saying that created solves your case, but it is phase supposed to get data. Just good practice.

Comment: Btw if information props are rendered in single block you can use v-if=information on wrapper and set default information to null. Then mutation after fetch should be properly observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the **correct** way to do this. But you can do it like this:

```html
<div v-if="information.name !== undefined">{{information.name}}</div>
```

Note that just using `v-if="information.name"` would not be correct.